# How to change line style while drawing in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw a dotted line from A to B and a straight line from B to C. If I use two draw commands, then there is an obvious break in the line, because I use rounded edges. Just using one draw command I'm stuck.

So is there a command like this:

```
\draw [rounded corners,dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1) [-]-- (3,1);
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node  at (0,1.2) {A};
\node  at (1,1.2) {B};
\node  at (3,1.2) {C};
\draw [rounded corners,dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (3,1);
\draw [rounded corners,dotted] (0,-1) -- (1,0);
\draw (1,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: No there isn't. Smooth cornering while changing the line type won't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not very nice, but can help you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1cm,convert={density=1400}]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) coordinate(A) node[left] {A};
    \path (1,1) coordinate(B) node[above left] {B};
    \path (3,1) coordinate(C) node[above] {C};

    \draw [ rounded corners,dotted,
            postaction={draw,line width=.5pt,solid,shorten <=13mm}]
              (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-3mm}]
      \draw[rounded corners,dotted]  (A) -- (B) -- (C);
      \draw[shorten <=2mm](B) -- (C);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Another idea is to use clipping. You can draw your path twice and for the first draw you clip half of the path, and for the second you clip the other half.

Comment: I'll try clipping, but so far [shorten <=2mm] is good enough.

Comment: Where is the documentation for `shorten <`?  I can't even find where this key is defined after attempting to grep through everything.

Comment: @A.Ellett You can find `/tikz/shorten >` and `/tikz/shorte <` on p.160 of the manual of v2.10. But strangely it is missing in the manual for 3.0.0.